# Issues with alert view, 'delegate' undeclared error

Tags: delegates, uialertview, delegation, abpeoplepickerview

This may be a school boy error, but I am trying to embed a UIAlertView after someone selects a contact property in the peoplePickerNavigationController that is NOT an address. What am I doing wrong to get a 'delegate' undeclared error! Could someone tell me conceptually why this is not working as I have made self a UIAlertViewDelegate and done the right things! Thanks in Advance :-)

```
- (BOOL) peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker 
    shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person 
         property:(ABPropertyID)property 
          identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
 UIAlertView *alert;
 if (property == kABPersonAddressProperty)
  NSLog(@"ZOMG YOU PRESSED FOR AN ADDRESS!!");
 else {
  alert = [UIAlertView alloc];
  [alert initWithTitle:@"Invalid Address" message:@"Please pick an address from a contact": delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
  [alert release];
 }

 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got an extra **:** here-

```
message:@"Please pick an address from a contact": delegate:self
```